# Canon 700d with stock lens or cheaper model with better lens?

Tags: lens, canon, equipment-recommendation, dslr

I'm torn between getting a 700d kit as it is or a cheaper model (ie. 1200d) with a better lens. Mainly plan on using it for short films. Opinions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for equipment to shoot short films with, you may want to put maximum priority on auto-focus and smooth focusing.
For example, if you need good focus tracking and not jerky focusing, you need a good body and also a good lens, preferably STM lens.

If you plan on using wide angles mostly, like within 18-35mm range, then focusing will not matter much and a low end camera will work satisfactorily.

So...
Get good camera, stock lens if:
 - You do not shoot moving subjects much
 - You will use medium telephoto lenses often
 - You need good auto white balance and exposure compensation

Budget camera (with touch screen) and good lens if:
 - You shoot moving objects and want smooth focus tracking
 - You are comfy using manual white balance and exposure settings
 - Want good bokeh and illumination plus contrast.

A camera with a touch screen is very good for movies.
By the way, do invest in a fast, UHS card or you will not be able to record much in HD.
Good luck!